# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am getting this error in tomcat server.

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-17" 
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-2"
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-15" 
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-20"
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-18" 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

I have seen MAT but how do I generate the `.hprof` file in my Tomcat server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

to remove the error edit the file

```
/etc/default/tomcat7
```

replace with:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1280m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

Then restart the web server.

`Xmx` is the new maximum size of memory and it should be affordable by your machine.

Comment: Number `7` is (of course) depending on tomcat version (for me it's `/etc/default/tomcat8`).

Comment: This location is the Debian way of doing it; I would also look into the Xms option in the other answers.

Answer (score 12):

add this line to `/path/to/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` (if doesn't exist create it) :

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m"
```

this increases tomcat's heap size to 1024MB.

Comment: If debian 7, usually `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh`

Answer (score 5):

Solution as per your OS:

if `Ubuntu`:

open .bashrc file available in user home folder (it is hidden) and Add or Edit one line among last 2-3 lines:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

else `Windows`:

In your environment variables add/edit

```
CATALINA_OPTS = "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu. If i write this line in .bashrc file what it will do. please tell me. whether it is increase heap size or export. If export how can i find that file.

Comment: I would not advise .bashrc. You want this configuration to be system wide, not specific to a user. On top of it, some Java instances (for example tomcat), run with their specific user, and as such, in that cases this configuration wont affect the Java instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to /bin and create a file named setenv.sh for Linux systems or setenv.bat for Windows.
2. Inside the setenv file, use the following format to set the heap size using the following parameters:

-Linux:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms4096M -Xmx4096M"
```

-Windows:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms4096M -Xmx4096M
```

3. Make sure both the values match for minimum and maximum.
4. Save the file and restart Tomcat.